# Dice league, putting players against each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, dice

I've got this code:

```
import random
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

#En spelarklass för ett enkelt tärningsspel med spelare
class Player:
   def __init__(self, name, score=0, wins=0, lastroll=0):
    # Attribut: Name, Score, Wins, Lastroll. Score, Wins och Lastroll ska alltid börja på 0
    self.name = name
    self.score = score
    self.wins = wins
    self.wins = lastroll

   def __str__(self):
       # Skriv ut vad spelaren heter och vad dens score är
       return f"The players name is: {self.name} and their score is: {self.score}"
       
   def __repr__(self):
       return f'The players name is: {self.name} and their score is: {self.score}'

   def add_score(self, points):
       # Lägger till antal points i score
       self.score += points
       return self.score

   def reset_score(self):
       # Nollställer scoren
       self.score = 0
       return self.score
   
   def win(self):
       # Ökar antalet wins med 1 för spelaren
       self.wins += 1
       return self.wins
  
   def roll(self):
       # Rullar en tärning och sparar resultatet i attributet Lastroll
       dice_value = random.randint(1,6)
       self.lastroll = dice_value
       return self.lastroll
   
def main():
    
    def league_of_dices():
            #Create a list of players (objects) as long as the input
            num_players = int(input('How many people should play?'))
            lst_players = list()

            for i in range(1, num_players+1):
                lst_players.append(Player(str(i)))
            
            score_list = []

            for i in range(2):
                for x, y in itertools.combinations(lst_players, 2):
                    first_roll = x.roll()
                    second_roll = y.roll()

                    if first_roll > second_roll:
                        x.add_score(3)
                        print(f'{x.name} won against {y.name}')
                        
                    elif first_roll < second_roll:
                        y.add_score(3)
                        print(f'{y.name} won against {x.name}')
                    else:
                        y.add_score(1)
                        x.add_score(1)
                        print(f'{x.name} tied against {y.name}')

            for i in range(0, num_players):
                ind_score_list = []
                ind_score_list.append(lst_players[i])
                ind_score_list.append(lst_players[i].score)  
                score_list.append(ind_score_list)

            sorted_score = sorted(score_list, key=itemgetter(1))
        
            print(f'Number 3: {sorted_score[-3:][0]}' )
            print(' ')
            print(f'Number 2: {sorted_score[-3:][1]}')
            print(' ')
            print(f'Number 1: {sorted_score[-3:][2]}')
            

    league_of_dices()
    pass
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I want to condense it, I feel like especially the if else part can be made a lot shorter:

```
    if first_roll > second_roll:
        x.add_score(3)
        print(f'{x.name} won against {y.name}')

    elif first_roll < second_roll:
        y.add_score(3)
        print(f'{y.name} won against {x.name}')
    else:
        y.add_score(1)
        x.add_score(1)
        print(f'{x.name} tied against {y.name}')
```

and I really want to hear suggestions, as well as the last part:

```
for i in range(0, num_players):
    ind_score_list = []
    ind_score_list.append(lst_players[i])
    ind_score_list.append(lst_players[i].score)  
    score_list.append(ind_score_list)

sorted_score = sorted(score_list, key=itemgetter(1))

print(f'Number 3: {sorted_score[-3:][0]}' )
print(' ')
print(f'Number 2: {sorted_score[-3:][1]}')
print(' ')
print(f'Number 1: {sorted_score[-3:][2]}')
```

feels like it could be made a lot shorter. Any suggestions and help would be tremendously appreciated! :) Also the last part im not sure how to print the top 3 more appealing, since I cant figure out a way to get `sorted_score` to be used as an object.

Comment: Hard to tell if the comments are accurate when they're not in English

Comment: Players are people, not things: "dens" should be "hens", or if you insist on objectifying, at least "dess"

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty nice already. I have a few mostly minor suggestions.

### Indentation

You use several different indentations in your code. The `Player` init method is indented by 1, some other parts of the the code are indented by 3, 4, and more. PEP8 recommends using four spaces for indentation, you're of course free to choose a different value, but be consistent.

### Documentation

Use [docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/) instead of inline comments to document your functions and classes.

For example:

```py
class Player:
    """En spelarklass för ett enkelt tärningsspel med spelare."""
    ...
```

In this case, it would also be a good idea to add a docstring at the top of the file that explains how the game works. It seems that a player that wins gets 3 points and in case of a draw both players get 1 point, but that's only clear after looking at the code.

### Duplication

The `__str__` and `__repr__` methods are exactly the same. Consider factoring that logic out into a separate function.

```py
class Player:

    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.to_string()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.to_string()

    def to_string(self) -> str:
        """Skriv ut vad spelaren heter och vad dens score är."""
        return f"The players name is: {self.name} and their score is: {self.score}"
```

### Nested functions

Nested functions should be used very sparingly. They make code harder to test and to reason about. Move your `league_of_dices` function outside of the `main` function.

### Variable naming

It's much better to use descriptive names for variables than short, generic names like `x` and `y`.

So in `league_of_dices` you could do the following:

```py
def league_of_dices():
    ...

    for _ in range(2):
        for player1, player2 in itertools.combinations(lst_players, 2):
            player1_roll = player1.roll()
            player2_roll = player2.roll()
```

### Check user input

Currently, your implementation will raise an error, if there are less than 3 players, since `sorted_score[:-3][2]` won't exist. So either make sure that there are always at least three players by checking the user input, or print the top 3 or less. You should also check the case that the user inputs 1 for the number of players, or even some string that cannot be converted to a number.

### `pass` statement

The `pass` statement after calling `league_of_dices` does nothing and can be removed.

### If-else block

I don't think you're implementation is particularly bad, but if you want to make it shorter, you could do something like this:

```py
def league_of_dices():
    ...

    for _ in range(2):
        for player1, player2 in itertools.combinations(lst_players, 2):
            player1_roll = player1.roll()
            player2_roll = player2.roll()

            if player1_roll == player2_roll:
                player1.add_score(1)
                player2.add_score(1)
                print(f"{player1.name} tied against {player2.name}")
                continue

            winner, loser = (
                (player1, player2)
                if player1_roll > player2_roll
                else (player2, player1)
            )
            winner.add_score(3)
            print(f"{winner.name} won against {loser.name}")
```

### Printing top players

This part can be simplified quite a bit. You already have a list of players and the players have an attribute `score`. Therefore, there is no need to create the `sorted_score` list, you can simply sort the list of players.

```py
def league_of_dices():
    ...

    sorted_players = sorted(lst_players, key=lambda player: player.score, reverse=True)
    for position, player in enumerate(sorted_players):
        if position > 2:
            break
        print(f"Number {position + 1}: {player}")
```

### Other comments

Does it make sense that `Player.win` returns the number of wins? Similarly, should `Player.reset_score` return the player's score (which will always be zero)? It's probably better these methods only change the respective state.

I think it would also make sense to add a separate class for your game (to replace the `league_of_dices` function). A lot of the state currently on `Player` probably rather belongs to a specific game or league. Whether you want to do that or not depends on how complex you want to make this application, in any case, I would take a look at that after addressing the comments above.

Comment: `for i in range(2)` , replace `i` with `_` . This clearly indicates that you don't use `i` and people don't go look for it or think that you forgot it. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Comment: Agree, and updated! :)

Comment: You have many good point here. Rather than pulling all code out into a separate function, maybe `def __repr__(self): return str(self)` would suffice?

Answer (score 4):

If you want your program to be in Swedish, great! Write the user-facing content in Swedish, and set locale as necessary. Don't write your comments in Swedish - code and comments should generally be in English, which (for better or worse) is the de-facto language of software development.

Your comments are not useful - they offer no information above what's already evident by reading the code. You can just delete them.

You need to trim down your `Player` class: half of its code is never used (`wins`, `lastroll`, every constructor argument except `name`, etc.)

`roll` is not a verb on the player. It can be a free function.

`league_of_dices` does not offer any value as a nested function.

To encapsulate the score logic, consider removing the `add_score` method and replacing it with two methods, `win` and `draw`, that respectively increment the score as needed.

Rewrite your score display loop so that `score_list` is a list of 2-tuples, score and player; do an in-place `.sort()` with the default key; then just loop through a slice of the list.

### Suggested

```py
import random
import itertools


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Spelarens namn är: {self.name} och deras poäng är: {self.score}"

    def win(self) -> None:
        self.score += 3

    def draw(self) -> None:
        self.score += 1


def roll() -> int:
    return random.randint(1, 6)


def main() -> None:
    num_players = int(input('Hur många ska spela? '))
    lst_players = list()

    for i in range(1, num_players+1):
        lst_players.append(Player(str(i)))

    for _ in range(2):
        for x, y in itertools.combinations(lst_players, 2):
            first_roll = roll()
            second_roll = roll()

            if first_roll > second_roll:
                x.win()
                print(f'{x.name} vann mot {y.name}')
            elif first_roll < second_roll:
                y.win()
                print(f'{y.name} vann mot {x.name}')
            else:
                y.draw()
                x.draw()
                print(f'{x.name} oavgjort med {y.name}')

    score_list = []
    for player in lst_players:
        score_list.append((player.score, player))
    score_list.sort()

    for i, (score, player) in enumerate(score_list[-3:]):
        print(f'Nummer {3-i}: {player}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

```
Hur många ska spela? 3
1 vann mot 2
3 vann mot 1
2 oavgjort med 3
1 vann mot 2
3 vann mot 1
3 vann mot 2
Nummer 3: Spelarens namn är: 2 och deras poäng är: 1
Nummer 2: Spelarens namn är: 1 och deras poäng är: 6
Nummer 1: Spelarens namn är: 3 och deras poäng är: 10
```